# CLLocationManager monitoredRegions causing crashes on iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

We are using CLLocationManager monitoredRegions in our code using a function

```
public func getMonitoredRegions() -> Set<CLRegion> {
        return locationManager.monitoredRegions
    }
```

And we are using this function in this way

```
for region in locationManager.getMonitoredRegions() where condition(region) {
   ...
}
```

We noticed that our application crashes when calling CLLocationManager monitoredRegions with the following Crashlytics log:

```
#12. Crashed: our.queue.name.here
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE 0x000000016aecffe0

0  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x191d9bfb4 nanov2_malloc$VARIANT$armv81 + 138
1  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x191d9c540 nanov2_calloc$VARIANT$armv81 + 136
2  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x191da9b74 malloc_zone_calloc + 140
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x191daa3fc calloc + 40
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1913ac554 class_createInstance + 72
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x191c05ad8 _os_object_alloc_realized + 40
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x191bd9594 <redacted> + 108
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x191bd78ac <redacted> + 1164
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x191bd7ab4 <redacted> + 56
9  libxpc.dylib                   0x191e1eeb4 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 204
10 Foundation                     0x192d8fa28 <redacted> + 12
11 Foundation                     0x192b574dc <redacted> + 3632
12 Foundation                     0x192b86eac <redacted> + 144
13 Foundation                     0x192d95a28 <redacted> + 72
14 CoreLocation                   0x1990cfee8 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 53660
15 CoreLocation                   0x19907d98c CLClientRetrieveLocationWithDynamicAccuracyReductionAndAlteredAccessoryLocations + 3712
16 CoreLocation                   0x19908cda8 CLClientStopVehicleHeadingUpdates + 53876
17 OurCustomLib                   0x108e2220c $S18OurCustomLib019LocationManagerCoreD0CAA0dE0A2aDP19getMonitoredRegionsShySo8CLRegionCSo8NSObjectCSH10ObjectiveCg_GyFTWTm + 56
```

or

```
#13. Crashed: our.queue.name.here
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE 0x000000016fc93fe0
0  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18d659fb0 nanov2_allocate$VARIANT$armv81 + 138
1  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18d65a53c nanov2_calloc$VARIANT$armv81 + 136
2  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18d667b70 malloc_zone_calloc + 140
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18d6683f8 calloc + 40
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18cc68554 class_createInstance + 72
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x18d4c3ad8 _os_object_alloc_realized + 40
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x18d497594 dispatch_mach_msg_create$VARIANT$armv81 + 108
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x18d4958c8 _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply + 1164
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x18d495ad0 dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply$VARIANT$armv81 + 56
9  libxpc.dylib                   0x18d6dceb4 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 204
10 Foundation                     0x18e64cc28 __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_WAITING_FOR_A_SYNCHRONOUS_REPLY__ + 12
11 Foundation                     0x18e41477c -[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:] + 3632
12 Foundation                     0x18e44414c -[NSXPCConnection _sendSelector:withProxy:arg1:arg2:arg3:] + 144
13 Foundation                     0x18e652c28 _NSXPCDistantObjectSimpleMessageSend3 + 72
14 CoreLocation                   0x194955f18 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 53660
15 CoreLocation                   0x194903a38 CLClientRetrieveLocationWithDynamicAccuracyReductionAndAlteredAccessoryLocations + 3712
16 CoreLocation                   0x194912e54 CLClientStopVehicleHeadingUpdates + 53876
17 OurCustomLib                   0x108e2220c $S18OurCustomLib019LocationManagerCoreD0CAA0dE0A2aDP19getMonitoredRegionsShySo8CLRegionCSo8NSObjectCSH10ObjectiveCg_GyFTWTm + 56
```

The code is inside a Framework and the Framework is used by an Application.

The Framework code is in Swift 4.0. All the devices having this crash are on iOS 12.

Is anyone else experiencing issues when using CLLocationManager **monitoredRegions** on iOS 12?

Please advise

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @sublimepremise No, I just noticed that I monitoredRegions was called too frequently in my case, I reduced the times when I call it, and it was no longer crashing.